# PHP MySQL Combining 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table genre

```
id | genre     | display
---+-----------+------------
1  | Action    | 1
2  | Comedy    | 0
3  | Romance   | 1
```

Table movies

```
id | genre_id  | movie         | year    | display
---+-----------+---------------+---------+------------
1  | 1         | Kill Bill     | 2003    | 1
2  | 1         | Die Hard      | 1988    | 0
3  | 2         | Anchorman     | 2004    | 1
4  | 3         | Titanic       | 1997    | 1
5  | 3         | Casablanca    | 1942    | 1
```

Query

```
SELECT genre.genre, movies.movie, movies.year FROM `genre` JOIN `movies` ON
genre.id = movies.genre_id WHERE genre.display = 1 AND movies.display = 1
```

I'm trying to write a sql statement so that I get the result below in this specific order. If a genre has a display of 1, then the genre itself will be displayed, as well as any of its movies that have a display of 1. Also, genre names shouldn't be duplicated:

1. Action

   - Kill Bill
   - 2003
2. Romance

   - Titanic
   - 1997
   - Casablanca
   - 1942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query selects the right rows.  I think the only issue is the ordering:

```
SELECT genre.genre, movies.movie, movies.year
FROM `genre` JOIN
     `movies`
     ON genre.id = movies.genre_id
WHERE genre.display = 1 AND movies.display = 1
order by genre.genre, movies.year desc;
```

If you don't want the genre to duplicate, you can use a funky trick.  That is, `union` the genres in with `NULL` movies, then order them correctly and remember to remove the names after that:

```
select (case when movie is NULL then genre else NULL end) as genre,
       movie, year
from ((select genre, NULL as movie, NULL as year
       from genre
       where display = 1
      ) union all
      (SELECT genre.genre, movies.movie, movies.year
       FROM `genre` JOIN
            `movies`
            ON genre.id = movies.genre_id
       WHERE genre.display = 1 AND movies.display = 1
      )
     ) t
order by genre,
         movie is null desc,
         year desc
```

Normally, I would say to do this in the app layer, but it can be fun to put together the SQL for something like this.

Comment: What if `genre.display` check will move into JOIN clause?

Comment: @raina77ow It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @raina77ow . . . It doesn't make a difference for an inner join.

Comment: its not apparent based on the output what the second order should be

Comment: @Orangepill the order should display the genre name once and go through any movies and its related years that it has. Also, there is a condition. Only those genres and its subsequent movies that have a display of 1 will be outputted.

Comment: @user1307016 . . . Do you actually want the years on different rows?  Your query suggests the year goes in the column.  Your example, though, shows the year as a separate row.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sorry i got things a bit mixed up. what you have up there is fine except i need it so that there aren't any duplicating genre names.

Comment: @user1307016 handle it on the application level.